# Unable to convert PyTorch model to ONNX: Multiple dynamic inputs needed

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I am new to PyTorch, and I built a custom BiLSTM model for sentiment analysis that uses pretrained Word2Vec embeddings. As the text I am passing in is variable in length, my **forward** method needs to pass in both the text and its length to use **pad_packed_sequence**:

```
 def forward(self, x, text_len):
```

The problem is trying to convert this model to **ONNX**.

My understanding is that the code should be something like this:

```
dummy_input_1 = torch.randn(1, seq_length, requires_grad=True).long()
dummy_input_2 = torch.randn(seq_length, requires_grad=True).long()

dynamic_axes = {'input_1' : {1 : 'len'}, 'input_2' : {0 : 'len'}, 
                'output1': {0: 'label'}} 

torch.onnx.export(model,
        args=(dummy_input_1, dummy_input_2),
        f='model.onnx',
        input_names=['input_1', 'input_2'],
        output_names=['output1'],
        dynamic_axes=dynamic_axes)
```

However, wouldn't I need to define **seq_length** first? How do I do this? And is this even the correct approach?